# Change data in div on key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to select element on basis arrow selection. I have a div and three element in list. now i want select first element at first time and when key down press selected element move to next li same as in third li and vice versa in opposite in key-up press.

HTML

```
<div id='divText'><div>
<ul>
<li>ABC<li>
<li>XYZ<li>
<li>CDE<li>
<li>FGH</li>
</ul>
```

Js

```
$('#divText').on("keyup", function(e) {
      var code = e.which;
      if (code == 40) 
           $('#divText').html($('ul li').html());
      else if (code == 38) {
           $('#divText').html($('ul li').html());
 });
```

Now i'm confuse that how we get next and previous element of ul

Comment: Your HTML is invalid to start with.

Comment: Use an `active` class, find the `active` `li` element, get the next or prev value based on that.

Comment: Describe your requirement correctly or create a fiddel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input id='divText' type="text"/>
 <ul id="list">
  <li>ABC</li>
  <li>XYZ</li>
  <li>CDE</li>
  <li>FGH</li>
 </ul>
```

JS:

```
var index = 0;
$('#divText').on("keyup", function(e) {
  var code = e.which;
  var max = $('#list').children().length;
  if (code == 40){
    index++;
    if(index == max){
      index = 0;
    }
  } else if (code == 38) {
    index--;
    if(index < 0){
      index = max-1;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('divText').value = ($('#list').children().eq(index).text());
});
```

...i missread the question in the first answer

Comment: Use `var max = $('#list').children('li').length;` instead.

Comment: yes, i did want to change this, but forgot to update it after trying it => edited

Comment: It's better to set `var index = -1;`. Here is another jQuery version: http://jsbin.com/AxAHIYo/2/edit